# Getting a directory name from a filename

Tags: c++, directory, filepath, dirname

I have a filename (`C:\folder\foo.txt`) and I need to retrieve the folder name (`C:\folder`) in C++. In C# I would do something like this:

```
string folder = new FileInfo("C:\folder\foo.txt").DirectoryName;
```

Is there a function that can be used in C++ to extract the path from the filename?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a standard Windows function for this, [PathRemoveFileSpec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773748.aspx). If you only support Windows 8 and later, it is highly recommended to use [PathCchRemoveFileSpec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh707092.aspx) instead. Among other improvements, it is no longer limited to `MAX_PATH` (260) characters.

Comment: Note that this function is now deprecated. The suggestion from Microsoft is to use [PathCchRemoveFileSpec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh707092%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: @Default: [PathCchRemoveFileSpec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh707092.aspx) is only available starting with Windows 8. Since Windows Vista and 7 are still supported, so is [PathRemoveFileSpec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773748.aspx).

Answer (score 168):

Using Boost.Filesystem:

```
boost::filesystem::path p("C:\\folder\\foo.txt");
boost::filesystem::path dir = p.parent_path();
```

Comment: `p.remove_filename()` will modify `p` in-place, and [may be implemented more efficiently than `p = p.parent_path()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-remove_filename)

Comment: If you might also deal with directories be aware of the fact that `parent_path()` from `"C:\\folder"` will result in `"C:"`.

Comment: lots of boost gets upgraded to std so also try this  .... include <filesystem>  ....                                                  
        std::experimental::filesystem::path p("C:\\folder\\foo.txt");

Answer (score 84):

Example from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/

```
// string::find_last_of
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void SplitFilename (const string& str)
{
  size_t found;
  cout << "Splitting: " << str << endl;
  found=str.find_last_of("/\\");
  cout << " folder: " << str.substr(0,found) << endl;
  cout << " file: " << str.substr(found+1) << endl;
}

int main ()
{
  string str1 ("/usr/bin/man");
  string str2 ("c:\\windows\\winhelp.exe");

  SplitFilename (str1);
  SplitFilename (str2);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the best minimal solution here.

Answer (score 63):

In C++17 there exists a class [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path) using the method [`parent_path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/parent_path).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
int main()
{
    for(fs::path p : {"/var/tmp/example.txt", "/", "/var/tmp/."})
        std::cout << "The parent path of " << p
                  << " is " << p.parent_path() << '\n';
}
```

Possible output:

```
The parent path of "/var/tmp/example.txt" is "/var/tmp"
The parent path of "/" is ""
The parent path of "/var/tmp/." is "/var/tmp"
```

Comment: There also exists a `.remove_filename()` method.

Comment: Thanks, @Qqwy, it also allows to use directory path with that method to get correct and expected results unlike the approach from the answer

Comment: Just be aware that `std::filesystem::path` may use `std::wstring` instead of `std::string` on some platforms, making it difficult to interoperate with normal strings...

Answer (score 17):

Why does it have to be so complicated?

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)         // argv[0] = C:\dev\test.exe
{
    char *p = strrchr(argv[0], '\\');
    if(p) p[0] = 0;

    printf(argv[0]);                    // argv[0] = C:\dev
}
```

Comment: This is not portable. Path separator in linux is '/'. std::filesystem::path is standard and portable.

Comment: Its not robust, but can be made portable. Portability is not always required. I prefer this than ask someone to upgrade to C++17 or install Boost.

Answer (score 9):

```
 auto p = boost::filesystem::path("test/folder/file.txt");
 std::cout << p.parent_path() << '\n';             // test/folder
 std::cout << p.parent_path().filename() << '\n';  // folder
 std::cout << p.filename() << '\n';                // file.txt
```

You may need `p.parent_path().filename()` to get name of parent folder.

Answer (score 4):

Use boost::filesystem.  It will be incorporated into the next standard anyway so you may as well get used to it.

Comment: Which standard are you talking about? I know that a lot of things from boost were added to C++ std lib, filesystem will be added too?

Comment: "It will be incorporated into the next standard anyway" And it's not

Comment: @AntonK maybe C++ 2017?

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson Cool, it seems included in C++17 - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem

Answer (score 3):

I'm so surprised no one has mentioned the standard way in Posix

Please use `basename / dirname` constructs.

man basename

Comment: The POSIX functions are not without their drawbacks. In particular they may modify the buffer that you pass in, (they really do mean the signature is `basname(char * path)` and not `basename(const char * path)`), and implementations that don't do that appear to have to use a static buffer which makes them thread-unsafe (in principle you could also return dynamically allocated results, but that makes you dependent on `alloc` family functions which is awkward in C++).

Answer (score 1):

[_splitpath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf(VS.80).aspx) is a nice CRT solution.

Answer (score -1):

Standard C++ won't do much for you in this regard, since path names are platform-specific. You can manually parse the string (as in glowcoder's answer), use operating system facilities (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364232(v=VS.85).aspx ), or probably the best approach, you can use a third-party filesystem library like boost::filesystem.

Comment: The standard's C++1z is currently attempting to adopt the boost filesystem library as of now making platform-friendliness much less of an issue. It's still in the experimental headers for MSVC, at least.

Answer (score -6):

Just use this: ExtractFilePath(your_path_file_name)

Comment: I believe this is a Delphi method, not something in C++.