# How to get the folder and file part of a complete path?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a full path like /a/b/c/text.txt

How to get /a/b/c and text.txt using c++? Prefer to use some standard library function.

I plan to use

substring, and find_last_of

Comment: Have you tried anything at all

Comment: I am trying to use some std::string method, but wondering if have the wrong direction at the beginning

Comment: Especially I would like to avoid Boost library, maybe. I know boost may support path method.

Comment: stl doesn't have anything to handle file paths. Boost does. If you can't use boos, you must do it yourself. Shouldn't be very difficult.

Comment: you may look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3071694/2082964

Comment: You've answered your own question.

Comment: @sgtHale - If you look at the timings he has added to the question my answer!

Comment: I answered the question. You added a comment and then modified your question to include my answer. The history is there for all to see.

Comment: @Ed Based on your answer and time history, you don't think I know how to use find_last_of as a try, please respect the OP in the future.

Comment: std::size_t i = str.rfind('/');

Comment: @Ed, please be professional like Chris; If you think it is a duplicate, just point out.

Comment: Adam - I wrote an answer - you then modified the question to include my answer. Sees rather odd. I note that you have deleted your comment to my answer

Comment: @Ed, please note, I am not writing find_last_of initially in the question (the added later) does not imply "I saw your answer, then based on your answer, modified my question"; this is YOUR logic only. I know several ways to try long time ago, but want to avoid unnecessary effort if std provides boost provided now.

Comment: @Ed, I deleted my comment to you since I don't think you have patience to discuss some interesting questions. I only discussed interesting questions with professional answerers. Hopefully you can be one in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find_last_of` - **http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/**

Along with substr should conjecture up a solution for you

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
std::string path = "/a/b/c/text.txt";
size_t lastSlash = path.rfind("/");
if (lastSlash != std::string::npos){
    std::string filename = path.substr(lastSlash + 1);
    std::string folder = path.substr(0, lastSlash);
}
```

Note that this works only for forward slashes as it is.

Comment: Personally, I prefer to using find_last_of, since it covers "/" and "\"

Comment: Why not just cover the appropriate one depending on the platform.

Comment: Ok, you can do that. I just realized they have an example basically identical to mine on cplusplus.com using find_last_of: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/

Some platforms (like Windows) use both.

Answer (score -2):

Based on the duplication(stackoverflow.com/a/3071694/2082964), I think the following solve the question,

Please note , depends on you need the trailing / or not; for my question, I need, so I modified a little bit.

```
 // string::find_last_of
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    void SplitFilename (const string& str)
    {
      size_t found;
      cout << "Splitting: " << str << endl;
      found=str.find_last_of("/\\");
      cout << " folder: " << str.substr(0,found+1) << endl;
      cout << " file: " << str.substr(found+1) << endl;
    }

    int main ()
    {
      string str1 ("/usr/bin/man");
      string str2 ("c:\\windows\\winhelp.exe");

      SplitFilename (str1);
      SplitFilename (str2);

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You should perform error checking on the return value from `find_last_of`

Comment: @Praetorian, what do you mean here? If find_last_of does not find, it will return -1, right?

Comment: It returns `string::npos` (which is -1). If that happens the subsequent `substr` calls will return incorrect results. Well, maybe incorrect. The *folder* substring will be empty, and the *file* substring will be the entire input, which may or may not be the behavior you want.

Comment: It is still OK I think. If found = -1, folder is str.substr(0,0) = "", which is expected, any more comments?

Comment: Do you mean I should use std::string::size_type , rather than size_t?

Comment: You should, but that's not what I meant. I edited my earlier comment to explain why I thought it might not be the result you want, but it looks like it is, so your solution works.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. In this case, it happens to be what I need; in other cases, I think you are totally right, I should check std::npos case.

Comment: @Praerorian, would you mind edit the answer if you think so?

Comment: Is this a cut'n'paste from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/ ?