# Regex-ed value to String

Tags: c++, regex, clang

I have created this regex and used the value to print out into a string.

```
 std::string s (filename);
  std::smatch m;
  std::regex e ("\/(?:.(?!\/))+$");   

  while (std::regex_search (s,m,e)) {
    for (auto p:m) std::cout << p << " ";

    s = m.suffix().str();   
  }
    std::string currFileName = s;

    std::string Original = filename;
    std::string newFile = Original + currFileName;
    std::cout << newFile;
```

The problem is it does not show in the terminal.

**Printed value**

```
/simple-loops.cc /home/fypj/build/simple-loops.cc
```

**Expected Value**

```
/home/fypj/build/simple-loops.cc/simple-loops.cc
```

You may ask what **filename** is

```
llvm::StringRef filename;
SourceLocation ST = f->getSourceRange().getBegin();
filename = Rewrite.getSourceMgr().getFilename(ST);
```

Comment: Yes, so what does the *filename string* look like? Is the printed value the same as the incoming one?

Comment: @wiktorstribizew /home/fypj/build/simple-loops.cc/

Comment: Does it mean you want to truncate the string at the last `/`?

Comment: @wiktorstribizew yes

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071665/getting-a-directory-name-from-a-filename

Comment: If you need to use a regex, use at least `"[^/]*$"` with `regex_replace`. See https://ideone.com/ge1OuT

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**: Perhaps, the best way to proceed is by using path manipulation method described, say, in [*Getting a directory name from a filename*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071665/getting-a-directory-name-from-a-filename) post.

Answering your question...

You are trying to match the last part of a path and append it to the end. You are using a regex that does not match your string because you want to match **one** or more chars after the last `/` that are not `/` - but your input ends with `/`. `"\/(?:.(?!\/))+$"` also contains `\/` wrong escape sequences, you should not escape the `/` symbols. Mind that this tempered greedy token like construct is not efficient when you need to "negate" just one symbol - you need [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

So, if you want to do it with a regex, use a pattern that accounts for `/`s and use it with `regex_replace`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::regex reg("/?([^/]+)/?$");
    std::string s("/home/fypj/build/simple-loops.cc/");
    std::cout << std::regex_replace(s, reg, "/$1/$1/") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/Cs5NLY)

**Pattern details**:

- `/?` - an optional `/`
- `([^/]+)` - Group 1 (can be referenced with `$1` from the replacement patter) capturing one or more symbols other than `/` (the `[^...]` is a *negated character class*)
- `$` - end of string

Comment: Right now, I have been using (http://www.regexr.com)  to get an expression but it seems that this website is not good

Comment: `std::regex` ECMAScript implementation is different from JS, so regexr is not so good to test C++ std::regex patterns. However, simple ones will do. Note that my demo above [produces `/home/fypj/build/simple-loops.cc/simple-loops.cc/`](https://ideone.com/Cs5NLY) result given your input is [`"/home/fypj/build/simple-loops.cc/"`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38736133/regex-ed-value-to-string/38736663?noredirect=1#comment64847593_38736133). Please be more specific about the input.

Comment: @HiWorld: If you failed to use this approach because of [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762492/regex-unable-to-print/38762657#38762657) please consider reviewing my suggestion again.

Comment: @wiktorsrtribizew Just testing out different options