# how to use C++ to get the folder/directory name, but not the path of one file? Especially boost::filesystem;

Tags: c++, boost-filesystem

```
    std::string file="C:\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3.txt";
fs::path file_path(file);
fs::path file_dir=file_path.parent_path();// "C:\\folder1\\folder2";
std::string str_path=file_path.string();
std::string str_dir=file_dir.string();
std:string str_folder=str_path.erase(0,str_dir()+1);// return folder2
```

This is the method I used. It works for me, but it looks ugly. So I prefer to look for boost::filesystems or other elegant code. 
Notes:
THis question is not duplicated and sligtly different from the question proposed  [Getting a directory name from a filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071665/getting-a-directory-name-from-a-filename). My interest is to find the filename but not the whole directory path.

Comment: thanks for help from @midor.    std:string str_folder=file_path.parent_path().filename()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `parent_path` to get rid of the last element in the path, then `filename` to get the last element.
 Example: include boost/filesystem.hpp and iostream

```
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
int main()
{
   fs::path p ("/usr/include/test");
   std::cout << p.parent_path().filename() << "\n";
}
```

should print "include".

Comment: thanks a lot. It works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use path iterators to find the last directory as well. It's not really much prettier though.

Example

```
boost::filesystem::path p{"/folder1/folder2/folder3.txt"};
boost::filesystem::path::iterator last_dir;
for (auto i = p.begin(); i != p.end(); ++i)
{
    if (*i != p.filename())
        last_dir = i;
}
std::cout << *last_dir << '\n';
```

The output of the above code should be `"folder2"`.

<sub>The above code uses Unix paths, but the principle is the same for Windows paths.</sub>

Same results from

```
last_dir = p.end();
--last_dir;
--last_dir;
std::cout << *last_dir << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked in another stack post. [Boost filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3071722/6702747)

In your case you can do something like this.

`boost::filesystem::path p("C:\\folder1\\folder2\\folder3.txt");
boost::filesystem::path dir = p.parent_path();`

Comment: In its current form this answer should be merely a comment. Please replicate the example here, instead of posting only the link.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of link that was posted.

Comment: If you have enough reputation you may flag the question as a duplicate, but posting the link as an answer isn't acceptable. THX for pointing out though, I hammered the question as a dupe now. Please gain enough reputation to comment and flag please. As mentioned posting such as an answer isn't actually acceptable.